# How can i deserialize a string Json Date?

Tags: java, android, json, date, gson

I'm new developing for Android, i want to deserialize a String of a Date value, and i was looking for deserialize the date converted into json like this /Date(1446063654000)/ to String like this formart YYYY/MM/DD.

But i dont find a solution.

Could you check it and tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/Date(1446063654000)/` seems to be a unix timestamp. Assuming you have it as a String...

```
String str = "/Date(1446063654000)/";
```

...converting this into a date is quite simple, as you could, for example, simply do..

```
long time = Long.parseLong( str.substring(6, str.length() - 2 );
```

In other words, take the string part after `'/Date(` (which is 6 characters long) until the last `)`, in other words, just the number part, and parse it into a long.

A long can be made into a date...

```
Date date = new Date( time );
```

And a Date can be formatted into a String...

```
String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format( date );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", Locale.US);
Date date = sdf.parse(string, parsePosition)
```

If you are using Gson library to parse Json string you can use:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
gson.fromJson(string, YourClass.class);
```

Comment: Do u have an example?

Comment: What example do you need?